# DataJpaTest is using same database of integrationtest and throwing error table already exist, if we run test case alone they are running fine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

Hi I have different test project module created  for IntegrationTest and DataJpaTest. When i am running test alone all test are running perfectly fine but when i run **gradlew build clean** test are not able to execute and getting some unsatisfied dependency injection error . I am pasting the screen shot of project structure and classes please let me know what I am missing here

Both jpatest and integrationtest are using same application-h2.yaml

Error

This is the result **gradlew check**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in com.successfactors.platform.db.TenantedDbConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'datasource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbPool' defined in com.xyz.platform.db.TenantedDbConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.xyz.platform.db.DbPool]: Factory method 'dbPool' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #5 of class path resource [schema-h2.sql]: CREATE TABLE X_EVENT_TYPE ( ID SMALLINT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, CODE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(40), DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(400), EVENT VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, ACTIVE BOOLEAN NOT NULL, CREATED_BY VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, LAST_CHANGED_BY VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, LAST_CHANGED_AT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ); nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "TIME_EVENT_TYPE" already exists; SQL statement:
```

Integration Folder class

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = TimeEventProcessingApplication.class,
webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles(TimeEventIntegrationConstants.H2)
@SuppressFBWarnings(value = {"UWF_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR", "SIC_INNER_SHOULD_BE_STATIC_ANON"})
public class AbstractTimeEventIntegrationTests  extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
}



public class CreateTimeEventIntegrationTests extends AbstractTimeEventIntegrationTests {
}
```

Data Jpa Test in different folder

```
@DataJpaTest(properties = { "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none","spring.test.database.replace=X" })
@ActiveProfiles("h2")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfiguration.class, TenantedDbConfiguration.class })
public class TimeEventTypeRepositoryTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
}

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = { TimeEventTypeRepository.class,
  TimeEventTypeGroupAssignmentRepository.class, TimeEventTypeGroupRepository.class })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.xyz.time.timeeventprocessing.core.entities" })
public class TestConfiguration {
}
```

Application.yml

```
  platform:
  database:
    globalschema: TEST
    dedicatedSchema: false

    datasources:
      - name: dbPool1
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDB;QUERY_CACHE_SIZE=0;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        hikari.idleTimeout: 300000
        hikari.maximumPoolSize: 20
        schema: classpath:schema-h2.sql
        data: classpath:data-h2.sql
    schemaStrategy: placeholder
    tenantSchema: XYZ
  monitoring:
    apm:
      enabled: false
  security:
    jwt:
      key: xxxxxx
      alg: xxxxxx
    
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        generate_statistics: false
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally use either [Flyway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup) or [Liquibase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-execute-liquibase-database-migrations-on-startup) to create database structure - then even if you run different tests against the same database, framework will detect that tables already exist.

If you don't want or are not able to use Flyway or Liquibase you can create tables with statement `IF NOT EXIST`. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products ...
```

Comment: is there any other way for datajpatest to create whole new context and recreate database and not to use integrationtest context

Comment: If you really want to recreate whole context use @DirtiesContext annotation.

Comment: DirtiesContext also not working already tried i am not sure how datajpatest is taking existing database

Comment: Is it an in-memory database?

Comment: Yes its using h2 database in memory if  i run test cases alone its working fine but when i run build its failing only in datajpatest, integration are runing fine not sure why this behaviour

Comment: how do you initialize database?

Comment: I have two script schema-h2.sql and data-h2.sql which is read by both integration and datajpatest using active profile h2 I am pasting my application-h2.yml for your reference in post